# How can I change my windows display user name in command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to change my PC's cmd user name. Is there any way to do that?
Like currently in cmd I get
`C:\Users\User Name>`
But I want
`C:\Users\User_Name>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the command `prompt`.
It would help if i could know what your username on windows is, but if we just say it is "User Name" we can craft a command.

So we start with `prompt $P` "$P" gives us the path so now our output is `C:\Users\User Name` then we can add "$H" which is a backspace. So if we add 5 of those we can delete " Name". Now our command looks like this `prompt $P$H$H$H$H$H` and that will give us this output `C:\Users\User`. Now we just have to add the "_Name". So now the command will look like this `prompt $P$H$H$H$H$H_Name` and we will have an output that looks like this `C:\Users\User_Name`. The last thing we have to add is the ">" at the end and you add that with "$G". Now we have our final command which is `prompt $P$H$H$H$H$H_Name$G` and will give us the output `C:\Users\User_Name>`. Try to see if you can craft your own command with your username.

To run the command every time you launch cmd you have to make a registry value in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` called "autorun" (type string) with your command as the value.